# Finding distance along a line (layer 1) where polygon intersects (layer 2) using QGIS

Tags: qgis

Layer 1 Line
Layer 2 Polygon

The polygon will intersect the line in 2 places.

E.g.

[image]

I'd like to attach the 2 distance values along the line to the polygon layer.

Comment: You could transform your Layer 2 polygon into lines using first the tool "Polygons to lines" then the SAGA tool "lines to points". Using this new layer you just created, toggle edit mode; get rid of all the points you don't want (depending on the size of your polygon of course), and perform a "distance to nearest hub - line to hub" on your two points.

Comment: @Tim56 Thanks. Worth a shot, although my layer contains a very large number of polygons and the removal of lines may be too time consuming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are open to using the Python console, I have written a PyQGIS script which should do what you are after.

Firstly, make sure that both your layers are in a projected coordinate system. If not, I suggest reprojecting them (right click on layer -> export -> save features as) and select a projected UTM CRS for your zone.

Secondly, please make a backup copy of your polygon layer just in case of unexpected results.

If you are not familiar with the Python console, just follow these steps (illustrated in the image below).

1. Click the Python icon in the Plugins toolbar or press ctrl+alt+p to open the console.
2. Click the notepad & pencil icon to open a new editor.
3. Copy and paste the script below into the blank editor.
4. Click the run icon to run the script.

The only changes you should need to make to the script is the layer names in lines 2 & 3 to make sure they match the names of your line & polygon layers.

[image]

Once you run the script, you should have 2 new numerical fields added to the attribute table of your polygon layer ('Distance_1' and 'Distance_2'). These will be populated with the distance along the line (in meters) from the start point of each line feature of the two intersection points with the polygon feature.

The script is not ideally optimized for one line transecting a series of abutting polygons, but I tested on a similar data set and it worked fine as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

Full script:

```py
# Change layer names below to match your layers
line_layer_name = 'Line_layer_A'
poly_layer_name = 'Polygon_layer_2'
project = QgsProject().instance()
line_layer = project.mapLayersByName(line_layer_name)[0]
polygon_layer = project.mapLayersByName(poly_layer_name)[0]
lines = [f for f in line_layer.getFeatures()]
polygons = [f for f in polygon_layer.getFeatures()]
# Add distance fields to polygon layer; you can change length & precision values if you wish

flds = [f.name() for f in polygon_layer.fields()]
if 'Distance_1' not in flds and 'Distance_2' not in flds:
    flds = [QgsField('Distance_1', QVariant.Double, len=10, prec=3), QgsField('Distance_2', QVariant.Double, len=10, prec=3)]
    polygon_layer.dataProvider().addAttributes(flds)
    polygon_layer.updateFields()

def distance_to_point(feature, point):
    geom = feature.geometry()
    verts = [v for v in geom.constGet().vertices()]
    point, minDistPoint, nextVertex, leftOf = geom.closestSegmentWithContext(QgsPointXY(point))
    start_to_vert_after = geom.distanceToVertex(nextVertex)
    point_to_vert_after = minDistPoint.distance(QgsPointXY(verts[nextVertex]))
    distance_of_point_along_line = start_to_vert_after - point_to_vert_after
    return distance_of_point_along_line

#create a spatial index to speed up intersection search on large datasets
index = QgsSpatialIndex()
index.addFeatures(lines)
# get indexes of newly added distance fields
dist_1_idx = polygon_layer.fields().indexFromName('Distance_1')
dist_2_idx = polygon_layer.fields().indexFromName('Distance_2')
polygon_layer.startEditing()

for p in polygons:
    distances = []
    test = index.intersects(p.geometry().boundingBox())
    candidates = [f for f in lines if f.id() in test]
    for f in candidates:
        ix = f.geometry().intersection(p.geometry())
        if ix:
            distance_1 = distance_to_point(f, ix.constGet()[0])
            distances.append(distance_1)
            distance_2 = distance_to_point(f, ix.constGet()[-1])
            distances.append(distance_2)
    if len(distances) == 2:
        atts = {dist_1_idx: distances[0], dist_2_idx: distances[1]}
    else:
        atts = {dist_1_idx: 0, dist_2_idx: 0}
    polygon_layer.changeAttributeValues(p.id(), atts)

polygon_layer.commitChanges()
```

Hopefully it works for you.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I think I have followed your instructions OK, but Im getting the following error.             Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Hi @Mardymonkey. Hmm, if the error is coming from line 5 it sounds like your line layer name doesn't match. Did you edit the script? E.g. if your line layer is called District_roads, then line 2 in the script should read: `line_layer_name = 'District_roads'` with your layer name as a string (enclosed in quotes). Same for the polygon layer.

Comment: Yep, my error on that one. I now have this error though. File "<string>", line 42, in <module>

Comment: Is there any more to the error message? It should say what type of error has been raised...

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 42, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Mardymonkey, that suggests that the list object called `distances`, which should contain the distance along the line of the first and last point of the section of line that intersects a polygon, does not contain 2 items. TBH I'm not sure how that is occurring. I have edited the code so that if the list does not contain 2 values, the distance fields will be filled with a zero- could you try it again now and see if it will at least run without error.

Comment: Just a thought- I think the only way that `distances` could be an empty list is if no intersections are found! It is very important that both your layers are in **the same** CRS and, to get a fairly accurate output in meters, it should be local, projected CRS such as a UTM coordinate system appropriate for your zone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104556/discussion-between-mardymonkey-and-ben-w).

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution created using the QGIS Field Calculator.

Assuming that you have more than one layer of polygons and lines, you need first of all add two new fields in the attribute table of your layers.

1. in the line layer add a new field called "id" and populate it with the Field Calculator and the expression `$id`
2. in the polygon layer add a new field called "line_id" and populate it with the id of the intersecting lines. You can use the expression

```
aggregate(layer:='line', aggregate:='concatenate', expression:=to_string($id), 
    filter:=intersects( $geometry, geometry(@parent)))
```

With this two new fields that connect the layers you can use the following expression:

```
concat(
round(line_locate_point( geometry:=geometry(get_feature('line', 'id', "line_id")), point:=end_point(
intersection($geometry, (geometry(get_feature('line', 'id', "line_id"))))))))
```

This expression can be used in the polygon layer as Label > Value > expression... or used in the Field Calculator to create a new field.

This is the result:

[image]

**ADDENDUM**
This expression shows the measure of the second point of intersection between polygons and line. If you want to have the first point just change in the expression from `end_point` to `start_point`.