# Entry and exit point of the polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, point-in-polygon

I would like to add to the attribute table somehow quickly a column containing the entry and exit kilometre data. 
I have the available point layer with kilometre, road axis and polygon as shown:

[image]

Usually I did it by changing the training ground to a line and then creating points at intersections. These points were later connected with the help of NNJoin plugin or similar tool with kilometre. The last step was to manually glue the values and organize the tables.

I'd like to automate (or speed up ) this process but unfortunately I don't have enough experience with using Python to write appropriate script. (I'm just learning it).

So does anyone know how to do it in another faster and a better way?

Comment: What can you tell about that part of the polygon where line goes out and rapidly in, i.e. 40+970 and 40+990 Shall those points be also considered as Entrance 2/Exit 2?

Comment: It would be best if they were taken as an exit and entrance 
I usually set it this way when I manually correct the tables. But such a situation is not so frequent, and if such a break in the field would be ignored, it would not be a problem.

Comment: Which criteria defines the direction of your lines? Simpy  a point number? e.g. 40 is an Entrance and 41 is an Exit, is not it?

Comment: Probably the answer in this post can suit your request https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/353510/156712

Comment: the direction of the line is set according to the direction of the numbers. so you can set the higher number is the output and the lower input..